What does a grid-cathode bypass capacitor on CRT do, and why is this one not doing it?
I have modified a (US) 1970s solid state B&W TV set for direct (NTSC) composite input for vintage computer use, in accordance with some equally vintage instructions specific to this set. The set now works fine and the direct input video works fine. BUT the instructions also suggest the following:

A 10 pfd capacitor [can be] connected from the screen grid (pin 6) to
cathode (pin 2) of the CRT to flatten out a peak the television's
response. This is not necessary on all sets but if so corrects a peak
which causes the character's left side to be brighter than the right
side.

These instructions are referring to the same model/chassis as I'm working with. I've verified that indeed pin 6 is the grid and pin 2 is the cathode (schematic from Sams below). When I connect a 10pF 1kV ceramic cap across these pins, I no longer get a picture. Removing the capacitor restores the image.
The "rationale" for the capacitor bears out: the left side of the displayed characters are indeed brighter than the rest of them.
What causes that effect, what is the bypass capacitor in that location supposed to do to alleviate the effect, and most importantly, why might that not work in my case? Why am I losing the picture instead of either (a) fixing the brightness issue or (b) seeing no change?
Thanks for any insight.
Complete modification instructions are in this document, pp16-17
Television schematic excerpt (tube pinout):


What type of capacitor did you use? Certain types have problems with high frequencies; a C0G ceramic disc capacitor would probably be your best bet in this position. At this vintage, they probably would assume you'd use either a C0G (or contemporary equivalent) ceramic disc or a mica capacitor for values in the 10 pF range. I'm not sure what precisely the role of this capacitor is, but if you used a rolled film capacitor or an X7R ceramic, parasitics may have caused issues.

@Hearth Thanks, good thought. All I know is it came from this exact kit: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CYC5CMWM?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details I assumed this would be more or less equivalent to something from the 70s, but perhaps it really isn't.

I wouldn't be surprised if those are all X7R or X5R or something. wouldn't put it past them to be Y5V or even Z5U, even.

@Hearth I found some nice silver micas and I’ll be darned, it works. Care to leave your comment as an answer ?

done! Sorry for the delay, my computer was broken.

This is the typical no-name  Amazon parts kit. These typically are junk unless you show by measurements that they are not. Don’t trust any ratings (value, working voltage, dielectric) on those parts unless you verify them yourself. They often are mislabeled, too. In other words: don’t waste time. Go to DigiKey, Mouser, etc. and just buy the part you need. I bet you it will work fine.  As others suggested, a C0G or NPO dielectric should be used.

It's probably down to specific capacitor you used. Certain types have problems with high frequencies; a C0G ceramic disc capacitor would probably be your best bet in this position. At this vintage, they probably would assume you'd use either a C0G (or contemporary equivalent) ceramic disc or a mica capacitor for values in the 10 pF range. I'm not sure what precisely the role of this capacitor is, but if you used a rolled film capacitor or an X7R ceramic, parasitics may have caused issues.
The cheap kit you linked from Amazon is likely a more modern, ultra-cheap (and correspondingly low-performance) type of capacitor. At best, they're probably X5R, but I wouldn't put it past them to be Y5V or even Z5U. That matters a lot! Modern high-κ ceramics fit a lot of capacitance into a very tiny area, but they sacrifice linearity for that--and they get especially lossy at high frequencies like those relevant here.

I have bought a few similar cheap kits and it’s even worse - some of them have made-up/fake ratings on the parts. Say a cap that breaks down at 350V will be marked “1kV”, a high-K part is marked NP0, the value can be out of tolerance, etc.

It's an amplifier bandwidth (frequency peaking) tweak.
We don't have enough information to conclude what value (if any) might be useful, but apparently the video amplifier has a response with overshoot, and apparently the capacitance is enough to tame it.  This is the time-domain description; the equivalent frequency-domain description is a peak in the transfer function, a low-pass characteristic where gain is ~flat at low frequencies, peaks in the transition band, and rolls off asymptotically above there.  Generally the effect will be to lower the asymptote, cutting into the peak; this may exacerbate the peak as well, which is why I say we don't have enough information.
For more information, consult the service manual for your display to see the circuit used, and research the topic of wideband amplifiers.
As for not working at all, video circuits typically run on 100V or more; use capacitors rated accordingly. Source parts from authorized distributors so you know what you're getting, or test unknown quality parts with suitable fixtures (I would want to see voltage rating, capacitance, linearity, and dissipation factor here).
